# datepicker issue- calendar size is too big

Tags: wpf, datepicker

The following xaml date picker (dropdown) calender and its days width is too big. how to reduce width of calender and days of calender.
Please help me to solve this issue

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="134"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions >
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Text="Client Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.client_name, ElementName=Parant}" 
         MaxLength="50"
         Padding="2"
         Height="25"
         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

<TextBlock Text="Building Location" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBox MaxLength="255" 
         Text="{Binding DataContext.location, ElementName=Parant}"  
         Grid.Row="1" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Height="40"
         Grid.Column="1" />

<TextBlock Text="Date" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
<!--<TextBox MaxLength="255" 
         Text="{Binding DataContext.survey_date, ElementName=Parant}"  
        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>-->
<DatePicker Name="DtpFromDate"  
                SelectedDate="{Binding DataContext.SurvayDatetime , ElementName=Parant}" 
                Margin="5"
                Width="230"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="25"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  />


<!--<TextBlock Text="Edit Lock:" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource= "{Binding DataContext.elockList, ElementName=Parant}"  
          SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.elock, ElementName=Parant}"  
          Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />-->

<TextBlock Text="Turn Around Time" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.turnaroundList, ElementName=Parant}"
           SelectedValue ="{Binding DataContext.turnaround, ElementName=Parant}"  
          Height ="25"
          Grid.Row="3" 
          Grid.Column="1"/>
```

please see the picture of calender, and give solution for solve this issue.
My date picker is shown like: [image: datePicker]

Comment: Looks like the width defined by you is too big. Try changing it to 150

Comment: Can you post the code of the enclosing `Grid`?

Comment: Do you have a TextBlock style or some other style that might be affecting it? I've had similar issues with that control in the past

Comment: my windows resource is:

Comment: i checked but in my windows.resource i set only  width , hight, margin and padding

Comment: write custom style for date picker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after adding  calender custom  style the problem solved

Comment: You could have shown the style, or it's not really a solution.